# Change bar dimension on mouseover event d3 js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, bar-chart

I am creating a bar graph and I would like to have a focus feature in it. So whenever I select, mouseover event, a particular bar, the width and height of bar increase and everything else remains the same making this bar more in focus. Something like this :-

[image: Before]

Lets say if I hover mouse on 2nd bar, it should look like this :-

[image: After hovering mouse on 2nd bar]

Is is possible to leverage focus and zoom functionality of d3.js?

Answer (score 0):

Threw something together for you https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/h1hdet8d/1/

It doesn't account for the axis/labels at all, but it should get you started. The idea is that on hover you increase the scale of the bar. Calculate how much more width it has, then divide that by 2 to get how much you should shift the other bars.

Important: Apply `.style('transform-origin','bottom')` to the bars so that they grow upward and to both sides evenly.

```
g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
      .style('transform-origin','bottom')
      .on('mouseover',mouseover)
      .on('mouseout',mouseout)

function mouseover(data,index){
    var bar = d3.select(this)
  var width = bar.attr('width')
  var height = bar.attr('height')

  var scale = 1.5;

  var newWidth = width* scale;
  var newHeight = height*scale;

  var shift = (newWidth - width)/2

  bar.transition()
    .style('transform','scale('+scale+')')


  d3.selectAll('.bar')
    .filter((d,i)=> i < index)
    .transition()
    .style('transform','translateX(-'+shift+'px)')

    d3.selectAll('.bar')
    .filter((d,i)=> i > index)
    .transition()
    .style('transform','translateX('+shift+'px)')


}

function mouseout(data,index){
d3.select(this).transition().style('transform','scale(1)')
d3.selectAll('.bar')
  .filter(d=>d.letter !== data.letter)
  .transition()
  .style('transform','translateX(0)')
}
```